# I want to convert all my existing UDTFs in Hive to Scala functions and use it from Spark SQL

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Can any one give me an example UDTF (eg; explode) written in scala which returns multiple row and use it as UDF in SparkSQL?

Table: table1

```
+------+----------+----------+
|userId|someString|      varA|
+------+----------+----------+
|     1|  example1| [0, 2, 5]|
|     2|  example2|[1, 20, 5]|
+------+----------+----------+
```

I'd like to create the following Scala code:

```
def exampleUDTF(var: Seq[Int]) = <Return Type???>  {
  // code to explode varA field ???
}

sqlContext.udf.register("exampleUDTF",exampleUDTF _)

sqlContext.sql("FROM table1 SELECT userId, someString, exampleUDTF(varA)").collect().foreach(println)
```

Expected output:

```
+------+----------+----+
|userId|someString|varA|
+------+----------+----+
|     1|  example1|   0|
|     1|  example1|   2|
|     1|  example1|   5|
|     2|  example2|   1|
|     2|  example2|  20|
|     2|  example2|   5|
+------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Honestly @zero323, I thought this was a duplicate at first too. But look at my amended answer below -- perhaps there is value in being able to pass a pre-defined function to `explode` instead of declaring one anonymously.

Comment: @DavidGriffin To be honest without type safety and with unchecked and non-exhaustive pattern matching I am not convinced :) Especially when `explode` is safe and doesn't require any additional code. But since OP posted another question which could be covered by your answer we can reopen this and close another one (http://stackoverflow.com/q/36549297/1560062)

Comment: WTF -- how many times does this guy ask the same question over and over and over?

Comment: Hey, @zero323, I edited my answer below. I don't see how my two uses of `explode` are any different in terms of type safety. If they are, can you explain?

Comment: @DavidGriffin Try to execute it on for example `df.withColumn("varA", $"varA".cast("array<bigint>"))`

Comment: Get the same error either way -- runtime errors of `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: My new question with slight modification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549297

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a `UDF`. A `UDF` can only add a single column to a `DataFrame`. There is, however, a function called `DataFrame.explode`, which you can use instead. To do it with your example, you would do this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val df = Seq(
  (1,"example1", Array(0,2,5)),
  (2,"example2", Array(1,20,5))
).toDF("userId", "someString", "varA")

val explodedDf = df.explode($"varA"){
  case Row(arr: Seq[Int]) => arr.toArray.map(a => Tuple1(a))
}.drop($"varA").withColumnRenamed("_1", "varA")

+------+----------+-----+
|userId|someString| varA|
+------+----------+-----+
|     1|  example1|    0|
|     1|  example1|    2|
|     1|  example1|    5|
|     2|  example2|    1|
|     2|  example2|   20|
|     2|  example2|    5|
+------+----------+-----+
```

Note that `explode` takes a function as an argument. So even though you can't create a `UDF` to do what you want, you can create a function to pass to `explode` to do what you want. Like this:

```
def exploder(row: Row) : Array[Tuple1[Int]] = {
  row match { case Row(arr) => arr.toArray.map(v => Tuple1(v)) }
}

df.explode($"varA")(exploder)
```

That's about the best you are going to get in terms of recreating a `UDTF`.

Comment: This is about explode but I want a way to build my custom function to be used as UDTF. Basically my function should take one column of complex type (Map ,Struct or Array) as input from the table and should split the individual entries to single row object and return List or Sequence of Rows.

Comment: I want a custom explode function in case I've to do operations on each sequesnce like:

Comment: That's great, what you want. That's not how it works. You got `explode`. Use `explode`. Or don't. Up to you.

Comment: Here, I edited it slightly to maybe get closer to what you want.

Comment: My new question with slight modification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549297/how-to-create-a-custom-udtf-like-function-in-scala-which-will-do-operations-and

Answer (score 0):

Hive Table:

```
name                                               id
["Subhajit Sen","Binoy Mondal","Shantanu Dutta"]   15
["Gobinathan SP","Harsh Gupta","Rahul Anand"]      16
```

1. Creating a scala function :

   `def toUpper(name: Seq[String]) =  (name.map(a => a.toUpperCase)).toSeq`
2. Registering function as UDF :
   `sqlContext.udf.register("toUpper",toUpper _)`
3. Calling the UDF using  sqlContext and storing output  as DataFrame object :

`var df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT toUpper(name) FROM namelist").toDF("Name")`

4. Exploding the DataFrame :
   `df.explode(df("Name")){case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(arr: Seq[String]) => arr.toSeq.map(v => Tuple1(v))}.drop(df("Name")).withColumnRenamed("_1","Name").show`

Result:

```
+--------------+
|          Name|
+--------------+
|  SUBHAJIT SEN|
|  BINOY MONDAL|
|SHANTANU DUTTA|
| GOBINATHAN SP|
|   HARSH GUPTA|
|   RAHUL ANAND|
+--------------+
```